# Algorithm to determine multiplier to reach specific number

Tags: algorithms

If I earn 10,000 dollars in the month of January and want to earn 1 million in the month of December by increasingly upping each month's income by a steady amount, how do I determine the multiplier? For example:

10,000 (January)

10,000 x 1.5 = 15,000 (February)

15,000 x 1.5 = 22,500 (March)

and on until 1 million is reached in December.

How do I determine the multiplier? It's around 1.5, but I'm very curious to know if there's a specific calculation that's faster than guessing and manually adding it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the multiplier. This is simply equal to solving the equation $$10000x^{12}=1000000\longrightarrow x=100^{\frac{1}{12}}\approx 1.4678$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$1 + k + k^2 + \cdots + k^n = \frac{1 - k^{(n+1)}}{1-k}.$$

**Edit**

> ...until 1 million is reached in December.

The above hint assumes the goal of all monthly payments, including December's totalling 1 million.  The alternative interpretation is that you want December's payment, **by itself** to be 1 million.

In that case, the alternative hint is

$$k^r = s \iff e^{[r \times \ln(k)]} = s \iff [r \times \ln(k)] = \ln(s).$$

Comment: I think they want the income in December alone to be 1 million, not the total income over the whole year?

Comment: @DerpShady Yes, that's correct.